# Write out the table in other method

Tags: java, arrays

Hey i want to write out table in second method. 
In first i changed int x into table(each digit in other array index) and in second method i want to write out the table. How to do it ?

```
int  tab [] =new int [4];
public int[] change(int x) {
    System.out.print(tab[0]=x/1000);
    System.out.print(tab[1]=(x/100)%10);
    System.out.print(tab[2]=(x/10)%10);
    System.out.println(tab[3]=x%10);
    System.out.println(tab.toString());

    return tab;
}

public void writeout(int a[]) {
    this.tab=a;//how to connect tab from change() with int a[]
    for( int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: You are missing a brace `}` for the second loop/function - is that's what's causing the trouble, or did you just forget it here?

Comment: You are *printing* assignations?

Comment: No, it's shows i have to write a=this.tab;. It's the right conecting :) what do you mean assignations ? i know what this word mmean but don;t understand

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with it. It appears to work after adding a closing brace at the end. `tab.toString()` doesn't result in sensible results though.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.writeout(c.change(3));
    }

    public int[] change(int x) {
        int  tab [] =new int [4];
        System.out.print(tab[0]=x/1000);
        System.out.print(tab[1]=(x/100)%10);
        System.out.print(tab[2]=(x/10)%10);
        System.out.println(tab[3]=x%10);
        System.out.println(tab.toString());

        return tab;
    }

    public void writeout(int a[]) {            
        for( int i=0;i<=3;++i) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to use class fields, then you could do it like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.change(3);
        c.writeout();
    }


    private int  tab [] = new int [4];

    public void change(int x) {
        System.out.print(tab[0]=x/1000);
        System.out.print(tab[1]=(x/100)%10);
        System.out.print(tab[2]=(x/10)%10);
        System.out.println(tab[3]=x%10);
    }

    public void writeout() {
        for( int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
            System.out.println(tab[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use newest Java 8 API to print your array. Your code may look like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {

    int tab[] = new int[4];

    public int[] change(int x) {
        tab[0] = x/1000;
        tab[1] = (x/100)%10;
        tab[2] = (x/10)%10;
        tab[3] = x%10;

        return tab;
    }

    public void writeout(int array[]) {
        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.writeout(app.change(2));
    }
}
```